# How to generate a random character out of a choice of two in Java?

Tags: java, random

I want to create a code that has a `50%` chance of returning the string, `"h"`, and the other 50% would return `"t"`. I understand there is a way of generating random strings in Java, but how would I restrict it to the point where you could only get `'h'`, and `'t'` from it?

It's a simple game of heads and tails. User inputs either h (heads) or t (tails) and the code generates the random answer.

Comment: getting only h or t is easy, but if you want it to be 50/50, it's no longer random. google "roll the dice java"

Comment: There's a way to get all sorts of random things in Java. You just need something that gives you two options. Have you looked at anything?

Comment: The only thing I can find is importing java.util.Random, but this doesn't seem to work in this situation...

Comment: what the input and the outputs you want exactly, can you share an example please?

Comment: @Tyler of course that works, as long as you use it correctly

Comment: `java.util.Random` is pretty good source of random, as is `Math.random()`.  If using the `Random` class with only two possible outcomes with a 50/50 chance, look into [`Random.nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the thread local random e.g.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

String ht = "ht"; // reused string
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current(); // reused Random
char flip = ht.charAt(random.nextInt(ht.length()));
```

What I wouldn't do is

```
char[] sequence = {'t', 'h'}; // creates a new array each time
Random random = new Random(); // creates a new Random object each time
char result = sequence[random.nextInt(sequence.length)];
```

> The only thing I can find is importing java.util.Random, but this doesn't seem to work in this situation

You really should be able to import this class. If not you either have, a broken IDE configuration, a cut down micro JDK, or your `import` is malformed.

It's impossible to say without reading the error message.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the code you said not to?

Comment: @Tyler I added comments. These create relatively expensive and needless objects. In most cases, it won't matter, but it's a bad habit to get into IMHO.

Comment: @zlakad true, though you probably want to avoid mutable `static final` fields in some projects. (unlikely to be a problem here though) e.g. a `String` is immutable and shorter to define.

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean :

```
char[] sequence = {'t', 'h'};
Random random = new Random();
char result = sequence[random.nextInt(sequence.length)];
```

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Any reason for `Character[]` instead of `char[]`?

Comment: I would advise against creating a new Random object for every call to nextInt.

Comment: no reason, it was a typo @phflack

Comment: It is just one call @Dukeling for that I make it like that, thank you I edit it, now it is more clear

Comment: The `Random()` constructor uses a seed unique-ifier which involves atomic variables and loops. So it's not trivial. Better to create a random at the start (as in the latest edit) or use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`.